# docker-compose wp cli doesn't print anything on commands

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I have this docker-compose configuration:

```
mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-mysql
    command: --lower_case_table_names=2
    volumes:
       - './data/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    networks:
      - app

  wordpress:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:rw,cached
      - ./config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    environment:
      XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
    env_file:
      - src/.env
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql:db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app
```

My Docker file looks like the following (after installing wordpress and mariadb)

```
# Install wp-cli
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo less mariadb-client
RUN curl -o /bin/wp-cli.phar https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
RUN chmod +x /bin/wp-cli.phar
RUN cd /bin && mv wp-cli.phar wp
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/.wp-cli/cache && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.wp-cli/cache
```

When I access the wordpress container I correctly see wp cli installed since I get this:

[image: Wordpress Container Terminal]

As you can see when I run the `help` command with `--allow-root` it doesn't print anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've had a similar issue in the past, except I did get an error. My issue was that `less` was not installed. Check to see if you have less installed with `which less`, if yuo have it, you'll see output like `/usr/bin/less`. If no out put, try installing `less` with: `apt-get install -y less` (or `RUN apt-get install -y less` in your Dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up to split the containers, so I have one for wordpress and one for wpcli, which works good.

Comment: That's a great idea